# Opencart accordion menu bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart2.x

I'm currently working on a website build with opencart and having some issues to get the sidebar menu straight.

I've got it working to have some more depth in the menu structure but now I need to have an accordien style menu since the page is getting way to long with al these categories.

What I currently have: http://mtdev.be/beenice/index.php?route=product/category&path=59_64_73_77
(notice that under Babyborrelkaartjes the subs are having that blue background but that should also be removed, since it's the lowest child categorie in this case)

This is what I need to achieve and what I could do outisde opencart: http://mtdev.be/b-nice/

I hope somebody is able to help me.

EDIT

I think I found something, the nextUntil function seems on the first sight somehow the magic thing I need in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("li.start").nextUntil("li.stop");
```

});

EDIT 2

Great, nextUntil really seems to be the trick.
Right now I have this code

```
$('.lvl-2').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.lvl-2').nextUntil('.lvl-2').animate({opacity:"toggle"});
});
```

Still, when clicking on a lvl-2, all lvl-3 are hidden.
So I need to find a workarround for that.

Comment: they all having `class="lvl-2 list-group-item"` and those with no blue background having `class="lvl-3 list-group-item"`

Comment: True, allready fixed the background color in another way but still no clue on how to fix the accordion thing.

The structure is:
<a class="lvl-2">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-2">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>
<a class="lvl-3">xxx</a>

The part that appears and disappears on folding is all lvl 3 links that are under the lvl 2
When it reaches to another lvl 2 that is another foldable menu part.

But I have no clue on how to achieve this with current opencart structure.